# Converting PNG to PDF. The Image is larger than 1 page and is getting cut off

Tags: c#, pdf, png, itext7

This code uses iText7 to convert an image to pdf.
The image is larger than 1 page and is getting cut off.
How would I convert the image that it spans more than 1 page in the pdf and is not cut off.
I need to cut the image into multiple pages.

```
 static void ConvertToPdf(string imagePath, string OutputPath)
        {
            ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(imagePath);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(OutputPath));
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4);


            Image image = new Image(imageData);

            image.SetWidth(pdfDocument.GetDefaultPageSize().GetWidth() - 50);
            image.SetAutoScaleHeight(true);

            document.Add(image);
            pdfDocument.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I don't do itext, but is there not a SetDPI call where you can increase it and thus compress it into a single page?

Comment: [Convert image byte array to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72210310/7444103)